# Swift - Sum function error

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make some view controllers that save a variable of a label every time and sum it to a total var. At the last view controller, show the result.

My code is:

### FirstViewController

```
@IBAction func playSystemSoundV1(sender: UIButton) {
    // Other code...
    puntsLocal = 3
}

@IBAction func playSystemSoundRet(sender: UIButton) {
    // Other code...
    puntsLocal = 5
}
```

This code is similar for 5 controller. At the end of the controller I have a button to pass from one viewController to another. When I click I do the code above:

```
@IBAction func puntuacioAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let puntuacion = Sum()
    puntuacion.sumPoints(puntsLocal) 
}
```

### Sum Class

```
import Foundation

class Sum {
    var points = 0

    // Method to sum points from every question.
    func sumPoints(num: Int) {  
        self.points += num   
    }

    func getPoints() -> Int {
        return points
    }
}
```

The problem is that returns only the last number without do any kind of sum. What can I do? In other languages it's very easy to resolve but in Swift I cannot reach the answer. Help please!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variable *outside* the function:

```
let puntuacion = Sum()

@IBAction func puntuacioAction(sender: UIButton) {
    puntuacion.sumPoints(puntsLocal)
}
```

Your original code created a new `Sum` everytime the function was called, explaining the behavior you are seeing. In Swift, variable declarations are *bound* to the scope they appear (e.g., inside a function, inside a class, etc).

If, besides that, you want to share this `Sum` object across many view controllers, this might help:

```
class Sum {
    static let shared = Sum()
    ...
}
```

and use it like this:

```
@IBAction func puntuacioAction(sender: UIButton) {
    Sum.shared.sumPoints(puntsLocal)
}
```

Of course, you should then delete the `let puntuacion = Sum()` line.

Comment: it's better do it but this doesn't solve the problem. When I debug, the var points is zero every round and it sums the num passed as argument to zero. It doesn't save the previous sum.